# Recreating the if/then block from shell script in C for use in shell scripts

Tags: bash, shell, primitive, control-flow

Wondering if it is possible in any way to create a function / set of functions in C that [compile to shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51918893/how-create-shell-commands-from-c-functions) for conditional evaluation. So for example, take a conditional block like [this](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.bash_prompt):

```
if [[ "${USER}" == "root" ]]; then
  userStyle="${red}";
else
  userStyle="${orange}";
fi;
```

That's just a normal shell script. I'm wondering if there is any way to create C functions such that you can alternatively write like this in shell script:

```
ifblock "${USER}" == "root" {
  userStyle="${red}";
}
elseblock {
  userStyle="${orange}";
}
```

*(I'm just using `xblock` to prevent naming collisions)*

If not like that, some alternative forms might be:

```
ifblock \
  ("${USER}" == "root") \
  (userStyle="${red}";) \
  (userStyle="${orange}";)
```

Or if it requires wrapping everything in local functions (if that's a thing) that would work too:

```
test_user() {
  "${USER}" == "root"
}

test_user_true() {
  userStyle="${red}";
}

test_user_false() {
  userStyle="${orange}";
}

ifelse test_user test_user_true test_user_false
```

Ideally something like the first way makes more sense, but basically I'm just wondering if there is any way to simulate control flow in shell script, without resorting to the control-flow primitives.

I am not sure what a C function would look like to implement this.

Comment: Are you saying "C function" when you mean "executable"?

Comment: Yes that is correct :)

Comment: I think you need to come to terms with the way the shell works. Remember that a shell is mostly a way to run external programs. What little syntax there is is fixed. As an example of how little syntax there is, note that `[` and `[[` are *commands*, not syntactic punctuation. The [Posix specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/shell.html) is not too long, although it doesn't include any bash extensions (like `[[`).

Comment: An essential point is that `if` is not like an if statement in any other language you know, because what it tests is whether a command succeeds or not. (In fact, it tests whether the last command in a series of commands succeeds.) What "to succeed" means is up to each command to decide, so the whole environment is a bit anarchic.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed write external commands that conditionally invoke commands specified as parameters. A typical example is `find`:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -q 'mystring' {} \; -exec echo "I found a matching file" \;
```

this is basically equivalent to

```
for file in **/*
do
  if grep -q 'mystring' "$file"
  then
    echo "I found a matching file"
  fi
done
```

However, since external commands require forking a new process, such a program would not be able to use or affect the current process' environment. For example, it can not:

- Modify variables in the calling script
- Read unexported variables in the calling script
- Change the current directory of the calling script
- Call functions that require any of the above

You can get a little bit further by writing Bash functions instead of external executables, but if you want to create a flexible EDSL then Bash is really not the right language.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there's something missing to this story: why implementing something conditional in a shell script without "resorting to" the usual built in control statements matters...any enlightenment, OP? (By the way, I concur with the conclusions of [@that other guy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1899640/that-other-guy) - a good list of cautions, and DSL-like things based on bash or other shells is awkward.)

That said, check my understanding: is the point of your example to be able to have a simple-looking command like:

```
ifelse test_user test_user_true test_user_false
```

...lead to the setting of the shell variable `userStyle` in a conditional manner? So that userStyle is set to the value of `red` in one case (user is "root"), the value of `orange` in the other?

If that's the case, leaving the current shell to invoke a separate executable named `ifelse` feels over-cooked. That invoked program only sees its command-line arguments - simple strings like "test_user", "test_user_true", "test_user_false". Presumably you want the invoked `ifelse` executable to know the above logic wrt to `red` and `orange`, but having an invoked executable affect the invoking shell is awkward and prone to security problems. Perhaps `ifelse` emits shell commands on its own that the invoking shell must (trust and then) `source` or `eval`. Seems pretty risky, and awkward to maintain, and the resulting use ends up not quite as simple in the invoking shell as you want:

```
eval $(ifelse test_user test_user_true test_user_false)
```

Staying within the current shell can work - maybe that's close to what you're after. Consider the following re-write of your code above (note the change to`test_user`):

```
red='This is the RED user style'
orange='This is the ORANGE user style'

test_user() {
  [ "${USER}" = "root" ]
}

test_user_true() {
  userStyle="${red}"
}

test_user_false() {
  userStyle="${orange}"
}

ifelse() {
  if "$1"; then
    "$2"
  else
    "$3"
  fi
}

ifelse test_user test_user_true test_user_false

echo "User Style: $userStyle"
```

Since I'm non-root, if I run this, I see:

```
User Style: This is the ORANGE user style
```

Back to my first editorial commend, if we're stuck using the shell, I'm still a bit unclear how the `ifelse` shell function buys much. Instead, consider:

```
if test_user; then test_user_true; else test_user_false; fi
```

No need for that funky `ifelse` function (and its cheerful willingness to construct an invalid `if` statement from unusual arguments), and does get the job done in one line.

Very possible I'm responding to an un-asked question. Apologies if so; wouldn't be the first time. :-)